# Lose Domain Dropdown Function after using Geoprocessing?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing, editing, domains

I have a large geodatabase with multiple feature classes.

I ran Geoprocessing- Arc Toolbox - Data Management - Features - Add XY Coordinates. Then I copied these values into our existing X Coordinate and Y Coordinate fields using the field calculator.

However, now my set domains do not drop down in either the table or attribute window.

Has anyone else had this issue? Does anyone know how to resolve it? I dont' want to lose my domain functionality.

0

Tom,

None of the fields I populated had domains. And what's weirder, is it stripped the domain function from some features, but not all of them, in the same feature class.

For example I have 2 features across the road from each other - one lets me populate domains with drop downs and the other does not.

I did this in other feature classes and still have drop down attribute function.

Comment: What fields were the domains on? Were those fields used in any of your processing?

Comment: Megan, please edit your question to include the information from your response to Tom, and then delete the answer you posted. Having something that is categorized as an answer on this post makes it less likely that someone will see your question and attempt to help.

Comment: Megan, you seem to have acquired two accounts. This will cause grief, like not being able to edit your post. Please see [this help document](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) to resolve this.

Comment: Can you edit any fields in the problem records?